# Can we implement linked lists using inheritance?

Tags: c++, linked-list

Is it possible to implement linked lists using inheritance? 
 for example:

```
 class List {/* ... */}; // abstract class
 class IntList : public List {/* ... */}; // derived class
```

Comment: Yes of course it's possible. But wouldn't templates be better?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You are absolutely right, templates are better,but I'm curious to know how this is possible using inheritance.

Comment: If you create a linked list using inheritance, due to up/down-casting, there's a lot of implementation-work for every version. verses with templates, its just automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to make the `List` base class to only handle nodes, i.e. keep track oh the list head, tail and adding/removing nodes. The `List` class could have a basic `Node` class that is inherited by e.g. `IntList` for the specialization.

Something like

```
class List
{
public:
    virtual ~List() {}

protected:
    // Protected constructor so this class can only be inherited
    List() {}

    struct Node
    {
        Node* next;
        Node* prev;
    };

    void add_head(Node*);
    void add_tail(Node*);

    Node* pop_head();
    Node* pop_tail();

    Node* get_head();
    Node* get_tail();

private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
};

class IntList : public List
{
public:
    IntList();
    ~IntList();

    void add_head(int);  // Creates an `IntNode` and calls `add_head` with that
    void add_tail(int);  // Creates an `IntNode` and calls `add_tail` with that

    int pop_head();  // Calls `pop_head` to get the node, and downcast to `IntNode`
    int pop_tail();  // Calls `pop_tail` to get the node, and downcast to `IntNode`

    int get_head();  // Calls `get_head` to get the node, and downcast to `IntNode`
    int get_tail();  // Calls `get_tail` to get the node, and downcast to `IntNode`

private:
    struct IntNode : List::Node
    {
        int value;
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. I love your comments by the way.